# How can I cancel hoverIntent on parent element when hoverIntent on child element fires?

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I have a parent element that when hovered over shows an element. I also have a child element that when hovered over shows a different element.

I don't want them both to fire at the same time - i.e. if you're hovering over the child I only want to show it's associated element - and suppress the hovering over of the parent element.

I'm having trouble getting this to work reliably. Probably missing something obvious. Any ideas?

**Edit - clarification:**

The "parent" and the "child" in this case are separate reusable components that don't know about each other, so I can't actually inject the context from one into the other

Here is the demo I've set up using jQuery & the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin.

HTML:

```
<div id="parentBar">
    <ul id="childMenu">
        <li>Menu 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="barInfo">
    <p>This is shown when hovering overing inside of the parent bar.</p>
</div>

<div id="menuInfo">
    <p>This is shown when hovering over inside of the child menu.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parentBar{width:500px;border:solid 1px black;}
#childMenu{margin-left:10px;padding-left:10px;width:100px;border:solid 1px green;}
#menuInfo, #barInfo{display:none;}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#parentBar').hoverIntent({
    //interval: 500,
    over: function(e) {
        $('#barInfo').show();
    },
    out: function(e) {
        $('#barInfo').hide();
    }
});

$('#childMenu').hoverIntent({
    //interval: 250,
    over: function(e) {
        $('#menuInfo').show();
    },
    out: function(e) {
        $('#menuInfo').hide();
    }
});

$('#childMenu').bind('mouseenter', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

You can view it here on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hNqQ7/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var flag = false;
$('#parentBar').hoverIntent({
  interval: 500,
  over: function(e) {
    if(!flag) {
        $('#barInfo').show();
    }
  },
  out: function(e) {
    $('#barInfo').hide();
  }
});

$('#childMenu').hoverIntent({
  interval: 250,
  over: function(e) {
    $('#menuInfo').show();
  },
  out: function(e) {
    $('#menuInfo').hide();
  }
}).mouseenter(function(){
    flag= true;
}).mouseleave(function(){
    flag = false;
});
```

Comment: So - is it black & white that stopPropagation isn't a valid solution? I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Because stopPropagation could work with THE SAME type of events. If you open the code of that plugin you can see that it doesn't use something like "hoverIntent" event and when you set over and out options - it's not a direct event handlers. Does my solution work for you?

Comment: If I look at the plugin it is wiring up its handlers to the "mouseenter" event - which is exactly what I've bound to the child element and where I've called stopPropagation() -- I appreciate the answer and I'm sure this type of tracking will work - I just didn't expect to have to resort to it.

Comment: Yes, the plugin uses "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events and `handleHover` function as handler for them. But when you set `$('#barInfo').show();` or `$('#barInfo').hide();` in `over` or `out`, you don't use handler otherwise you'll prevent all actions generally. These are callback functions from plugin configuration, and plagun calls them inside `handleHover` (see `compare` and `delay`). So you can't prevent callling handler using stopPropagation, because the handler has been called already.

Answer (score 1):

In the child event (both functions), call [e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Edit:
Ok, sorry, I didn't look at the demo previously.  You can change the child code to the following:

```
$('#childMenu').hoverIntent({
   interval: 250,
   over: function(e) {
        $('#barInfo').hide();
        $('#menuInfo').show();
    },
    out: function(e) {
        $('#barInfo').show();
        $('#menuInfo').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hNqQ7/2/ - here's the demo with that change made, same behavior.

Comment: I guess I should clarify that the "parent" and the "child" in this case are separate reusable components that don't know about each other, so I can't actually inject the context from one into the other.

Comment: One is going to have to be aware of the other if they are going to be nested.  Otherwise, the mouseover event is still valid for both elements.

Answer (score 0):

This solution modifies the core plugin.

Using the latest version of hoverIntent, https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent , I made a simple modification to the core function, **compare**, triggered from mouseenter.

Find (~line 65):

```
if (Math.sqrt((s.pX - cX) * (s.pX - cX) + (s.pY - cY) * (s.pY - cY)) < cfg.sensitivity) {
```

And replace with:

```
if (!$el.hasClass("preventIntent") && Math.sqrt((s.pX - cX) * (s.pX - cX) + (s.pY - cY) * (s.pY - cY)) < cfg.sensitivity) {
```

This allows you to create any logic from children/separate interactions and suppress the hoverIntent's "over" function by toggling the class **preventIntent** .

Example:

```
$(".child-ele").on("mouseenter", function(e) {
    $(this).closest(".parent-ele").addClass("preventIntent");
}).on("mouseleave", function(e) {
    $(this).closest(".parent-ele").removeClass("preventIntent");
});
```

Alternatively, the core plugin could be improved with an "ignoreChild" option selector, that performs a check of .is(":hover") on each loop. This could reduce the need of extra mouse events, but restricts it to hovers only obviously.

Comment: I know this is two years old, but ... holycarp, why wasn't this included in the original? I suggest posting the suggestion as a github `issue` or `pull request`, which I'll promptly +1 :)